# How to rename multiple branches in git?

Tags: git

We have an convention to add a prefix before branch name. Of course not every one followed that convention and now we have multiple branches that do not have a prefix.

So the task is to write a command(s) that:

1) get all branches that do not have one of the feature/bugfix/hotfix prefix

2) rename all those branches and add them a (lets say "misc") prefix

3) do not touch master branch

I did found something like this:

```
git branch | grep defects | awk '{original=$1; sub("defects","old-defects"); print original, $1}' | xargs -n 2 git branch -m
```

but I do not know who to reuse it in my situation

regards

mW

Comment: I recommend against renaming many branches, because I think it might cause issues for anyone who has the old branch name checked out.  Branches in Git tend to be transient things anyway.  Just enforce the convention moving forward.  If you are really paranoid, you might be able to setup a local/remote Git hooks which checks the branch name before someone tries to create it.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen I'm aware of this but as I looked at those branches. They are quite old ones so we should not have such issue. Thanks for idea about hooks in bitbucket. For sure I will give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

```
git branch --list \
    | tr -d ' *' \
    | egrep -v '^master$' \
    | egrep -v '^(feature|bugfix|hotfix)_' \
    | xargs -n 1 -I % echo git branch -m % misc_%
```

Remove the `echo` if you want to really run the `git` command.

Comment: is there a way to test this before running?

Comment: Use `git for-each-ref`, not `git branch`, to iterate over reference names. The key difference is that `git for-each-ref` is a *plumbing command:* one whose output is designed for use by other programs. This does mean you have to use `git for-each-ref refs/heads`, typically with a `--format` argument as well, but avoids needing to delete the blanks and `*` and never gets tripped-up by colorized output. (You can also simplify the grepping, but otherwise this looks fine.)